# jQuery $.extend() not extending the object

Tags: jquery, object

Working on a simple calendar script, trying to make it possible for events to be posted to the proper day; however the jQuery `$.extend` is not extending my `options` object. Here is the snippet from the HTML file:

```
$("#cal").calendar({
    month: 2,
    events: [{
        date: "2013-4-10",
        workorder: 1234567890,
        district: 01,
        range: "2:00pm - 4:00pm",
        appNotes: "This is just a sample of some notes... end",
        installer: "John Doe",
        cityNotes: "This is just another sample of some notes... end"
    }, {
        date: "2013-4-1",
        workorder: 1234567890,
        district: 01,
        range: "3:00pm - 5:00pm",
        appNotes: "This is just a sample of some notes... end",
        installer: "John Doe",
        cityNotes: "This is just another sample of some notes... end"
    }]
});
```

And the beginning of my plug in:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.calendar = function(options){
        var defaults= {
            month: null,
            prev: "prevMonth",
            curr: "currMonth",
            next: "nextMonth",
            events: []
        }, options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return($(this).each(function(){
            var obj = $(this),
            // Etc...
```

I'm able to access properties of the object, however it is not being extended as thought. Any ideas?

Comment: I've done it a million times this way and never had a problem @jahroy

Comment: Yep... @SeanVieira looks to have the right answer.  About to delete my silly comment.

Comment: I thank you for taking a look either way @jahroy

Answer (score 4):

[`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) extends the *first* object passed in - rather than doing `$.extend(defaults, options)` do `$.extend({}, defaults, options)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.calendar = function(options){
        var defaults= {
            month: null,
            prev: "prevMonth",
            curr: "currMonth",
            next: "nextMonth",
            events: []
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

Also: remember that the Target is the first object... so in this example, defaults would have been extended with options...